# react hooks : Uncaught TypeError: data.posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a list of jokes but it is saying " TypeError: data.posts.map is not a function ". 
    I used before same code but different API and it was working.
    In console it is showing those posts but on app i get error saying that " data.posts.map "
    Can anyone help me?
    Thanks
    This is my code:

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    const PostArea = () => {

      const [like, showLike] = useState(false);
      const [color, setColor] = useState('#000');

      const likePrint = () => {
        showLike(!like);
      }

      const [data, setPost] = useState({ posts: [] });

      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const result = await axios('https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist&idRange=0-40');
          console.log({ posts: result.data });
          setPost({ posts: result.data });
        };
        fetchData();
      }, []);
      return (
        <div>
          {data.posts && data.posts.map(({ id, setup, delivery, category }) => {
            return (
              <div key={id} className="post">
                <div className="header">
                  <a>
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/40" alt=" title" />
                    <div>
                      <span className="detail">Category :{category}</span>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                  <p>
                    {setup}
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    {delivery}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className="footer">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a style={{ color: color }} onClick={() => { likePrint(!like); setColor('#2274a5') }}>
                        <i className="fas fa-heart"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <i className="fas fa-comment"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <i className="fas fa-share-alt-square"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default PostArea;
```

Error : Uncaught TypeError: data.posts.map is not a function

Comment: Did you check type of `result.data` to make sure it is an array?
I guess  type of `result.data` which you get from the API might not be an array.

Comment: I thought if i use useState({ posts: [] }) it was transforming into an array

Comment: JS is very flexible about type, you can assign a type for a variable and you can re-assign it to any other type. When ` useState({ posts: [] })` the posts is an array then you set `setPost({ posts: result.data })` the type of `posts` will be the type of `result.data`

Comment: By setting a breakpoint in the Dev tools (e.g. in Chrome -> Right click -> inspect) you can inspect the value of `data` upon render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the response from the `https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist&idRange=0-40`, and it seems like it is returning an object, rather an array, which is the expected type of `data.post`.

I guess you would want to include this object as part of the `post` array?

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios('https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?blacklistFlags=nsfw,religious,political,racist,sexist&idRange=0-40');
  setPost({ posts: [result.data] });
};
```